# What are Pu and Pz in the Phillips & Ouliaris cointegration test?

Tags: r, cointegration

I see the type parameter for Phillips & Ouliaris Cointegration Test in the `urca` package that should be Pz or Pu. I read the details, but I don't understand what type is useful for me. If I wanted to check the cointegration with that method for two series of stock prices, what type would be better?

In other words, what does the following mean?

> The test "Pz", compared to the test "Pu", has the advantage that it is
>   invariant to the normalization of the cointegration vector, i.e. it
>   does not matter which variable is on the left hand side of the
>   equation. In case convergence problems are encountered by matrix
>   inversion, one can pass a higher tolerance level via "tol=..." to the
>   solve()-function.